# Javascript: is it a bad practice to instantiate a class inside method?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

```
class A {}

class B {
 foo() {
   const a = new A();
 }
}
```

I know in other OOP languages it is a sin. Objects are passed by a dependency injector (getter or constructor).

As far as I remember, the main issue with that syntax is unit-testing. 
In the example above, if it was OOP language, it would be hard to test the method `foo()` as it's impossible to mock the class `A`.
However, Javascript is different, and the mocking is possible in this situation.

Comment: If you can't test class `A`, wouldn't that be a problem with `A` instead of the fact that a `B` contains it? Regardless, this question is probably more suitable for Software Engineering SE, although I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Class `A` is not the problem, you can test it. It doesn't have any dependencies.